# How to construct an algebraic function that is not rational?

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, power-series

How to construct a algebraic irrational function $f(x)$ such that $$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i x^i$$ with $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_i,\dots \in \mathbb{N}$.

Reference is appreciated.

**Update**: an instance is $$f(x)=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}} =\sum  C_n x^n$$ with $c_n$ being the
$n_{th}$  Catalan number. Thank to Jyrki Lahtonen.

And some are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)

Hope more examples.

Comment: The question needs a bit of context such as why are you interested?  Anyway, you can look up [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: You always have $(1-x)^\alpha$ which is  algebraic and irrational if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{N}$. The convergence radius is $1$.

Comment: @GreginGre The spec is that the coefficients are nonnegative integers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Just for fun and curiosity, because we construct such transcendental power series and rational series easity, but it is hardly encount such a algebraic irrational one

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73553/when-may-function-meromorphic-be-expanded-as-power-series-with-coefficients-of

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen， thanks，$$f(x)=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4x}} =\sum  C_n x^n$$ with $c_n$ being the 
 $n_{th}$  Catalan number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know [Eisenstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_theorem)? It states that if you have any algebraic power series
$$f(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n$$
with $a_n \in \mathbb Q$, then there is a number $A \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n A^n \in \mathbb Z$ for all $n$. In other words, the power series
$$g(z) = f(Az) = \sum (a_n A^n) z^n$$
has integral coefficients.
For example if
$$f(z) = \sqrt{1+z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\frac 1 2}{k} z^k,$$
I'm pretty sure that $$g(z) = \sqrt{1+4z}$$ has integral coefficients (though I'm a bit stupid proving it right now...). Exercise!

Answer (score 9):

I fully endorse Red_Trumpet's solution (particularly the reference to Eisenstein's theorem I was not aware of). Posting as an alternative the use of algebraic equations that recursively define the solution as a power series of the required type.

For example, consider the equation
$$y=1+x y^3,\qquad(*)$$
when we can immediate deduce that the solution $y$ is algebraic over the rational function field $\Bbb{Q}(x)$. Furthermore, we see that we get $y$ as an element of
$\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$
using $x$-adic iteration. Begin by defining $y_0(x)=1$, and then use the recurrence relation
$$
y_{n+1}(x)=1+x y_n(x)^3.
$$
It follows immediately, by induction on $n$, that for all $n$ we have $y_n(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$. Furthermore, we see that for all $n\ge1$, the polynomials $y_{n+1}(x)$ and $y_n(x)$ differ from each other by a multiple of $x^{n+1}$. Therefore the sequence $y_n(x)$ converges (with respect to the $x$-adic topology) to a power series in $\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$. Here
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_0(x)&=1,\\
y_1(x)&=1+x,\\
y_2(x)&=1+x+3x^2+3x^3+x^4,\\
y_3(x)&=1+x+3x^2+12x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^4),\\
y_4(x)&=1+x+3x^2+12x^3+55x^4+\mathcal{O}(x^5),\\
\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
It follows that the limit
$$y=y(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n(x)=1+x+3x^2+12x^3+55x^4+273x^5+\cdots$$ satisfies the equation $(*)$, and hence is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}(x)$. Rewriting $(*)$
as
$$
y^3-\frac1x\,y+\frac1x=0
$$
reveals that $y\notin\Bbb{Q}(x)$ (Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion at the infinite place with local parameter $p=1/x$).

---

We get the generating function of [the Catalan numbers $c_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $c(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$, when combinatorial study reveals the equation
$$
c(x)=1+x c(x)^2\qquad(**)
$$
that can then be used as above to prove that $c(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$. Alternatively, the equation $(**)$ can simply be solved by the quadratic formula, and the power series written down explicitly with the aid of the binomial series.

---

I guess I should describe a general condition when an equation like $(*)$ defines a power series, but I don't know anything about that. I simply felt like sharing :-)

Comment: Feeding the early part of my example power series to OEIS gives [this hit](https://oeis.org/A001764). There must be something to it, but I need to leave to others :-(

Comment: Excellent and thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like the Catalan series produces the patalan numbers ( somebody named them that way)

$$\frac{1-(1-p^2 x)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{p x} = \sum_{n\ge 0} C_{p,n} x^n$$

with $C_{p,n}$ positive integers for every $p\ne 0$ integer ( for $p=2$ we get $C_{2,n} = C_n$ the usual Catalan).  From here one also concludes that

$$-\frac{1-(1-p^2 x)^{-\frac{q}{p}}}{p x}$$
also has integer coefficients, which are, for every $n$

$$\frac{p^{n-1}q(q+p)\cdots (q+(n-1) p)}{n!}$$

(and an older result from this)